# Merging 2 addMethods in one for validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have 2 addMethods applied on one inputbox

**Note: I need 2 error messages like empty error and valid url if one of them is invalid in one addMethod.**

1 - Check required
2 - Check URL validation.

**Is there a way to merge both and get the same result?**

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("complete_req", function (val, elem) {

    var value = $.trim($("#linkTypeDd").val());
    if (value == "2") 
    {
        if (val.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }
            return true;
    }
},"");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("complete_url", function (val, elem) {

        var value = $.trim($("#linkTypeDd").val());
        if (value == "2") {
            // if no url, don't do anything
            if (val.length == 0) {return true;}

            // if user has not entered http:// https:// or ftp:// assume they mean http://
            if (!/^(https?|ftp):\/\//i.test(val)) {
                val = 'http://' + val; // set both the value
                $(elem).val(val); // also update the form element
            }

            // now check if valid url
            // http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/url
            return "Suppose this is url rejex";
        }

        return true;
    });

    jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";
    var validator = $("#footer-form").validate({
        debug: true,

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit(formoptions);
        },

        invalidHandler: function (e, validator) {
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                var message = errors == 1 ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted.' : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields.  They have been highlighted.';
                showMessage("#error", message);
                $("#success").hide();
            }
            else {
                $("#error").hide();
            }
        },

        rules:
        {
            DisplayName: "required",
            UrlName: "required",
            ExternalPath: {
                complete_req : true,
                url: "complete_url"
            }
        },

        errorClass: "invalid",
        validClass: "valid",
        errorContainer: "#error"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think merging both rules to a single one is the only way. ie merging the logics in both methods to single one and convert it to single add method and a single rule.

```
var value = $.trim($("#linkTypeDd").val());
    if (value == "2") 
    {
        if (val.length == 0) {
            return false;   //means required
        }
        else
        {
            // here you have to do the checking for valid url  
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand what you are saying but how can I show multiple error messages like required error if passed than URL validity error. Thats the important thing and I can not find the answer after alot of googling. Any idea?

Comment: you can do one thing, in the method first check for required condition, if it fails means show the required error. If the required condition succeeded means check for valid url and if it fails means show the error for valid url

Comment: Can you edit my code and show me. Tried but not working please.